# Terminate function in Perl with unless

Tags: perl

What does the following mean in Perl?

```
 my $workbook;
 $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new($outputfile);
 terminate("Problems creating new Excel file: $!", 'BATCH_CRITICAL') unless defined $workbook;
```

I have just started learning Perl so I can understand the first two lines, just having trouble to understand the 3rd line with terminate function. What do the `terminate` function and `unless defined` do here?

Is there any document or page link where I can read about terminate function with unless defined condition?

Comment: The `terminate` function must be defined somewhere in this code, i.e. it is not a standard Perl function. `unless` means `if not`. Essentially this means that `terminate` will be called if `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new` failed. As for documentation: there are many many Perl books or online introductions out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is equivalent to:

```
my $workbook;
$workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new($outputfile);

if (!defined($workbook)) {
    terminate("Problems creating new Excel file: $!", 'BATCH_CRITICAL');
}
```

[`Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel#new()) returns `undef` if it fails as noted in the documentation:

> If the file cannot be created, due to file permissions or some other reason, new will return `undef`. Therefore, it is good practice to check the return value of new before proceeding. As usual the Perl variable `$!` will be set if there is a file creation error.

The `terminate` function is not a Perl built-in. It must be part of the code base you are studying. From what I can tell, it provides a common point for logging the errors encountered.

If you are having problems with this, you are not at a point you should be diving head first into complicated programs. Better to get a [good book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920049517.do) and learn the basics first.

Comment: Thanks a ton Sinan!  That helps a lot.